# How to fix error No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource when using S3 and Cloudfront of Amazon

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors, amazon-cloudfront

When I config S3 and Cloudfront to secure my premium files, I have a problem with Cross-Origin from Cloudfront I have researched and found this [link](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/no-access-control-allow-origin-error/) and follow that tutorial to fix my error, but it not working.

Below is my error and my configs:

[Error from Web Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfhKn.png)

**1. Cloudfront Behavior Config**

[Behavior 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kv2SX.png)

[Behavior 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSHQI.png)

**2. S3 Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) Config**

[S3 CORS Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gn0mE.png)

[S3 Policy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mO0O.png)

I spent much time researching and fix that but can not, please help me to fix that or tell me which I'm wrong to configs?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration looks correct.

Try invalidating your Cloudfront distribution's cache, wait for the invalidation to complete and access the files again.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
I have deleted the cache of Cloudfront distribution and waiting for 1 day but that bug cannot fix yet. I don't know why, maybe I need to change the config of Nginx on my server to allow Cors? Do you have any idea for fix this bug?